# how to make android app visible / installable to almost all devices through play store?

Tags: android, google-play, visibility

I have used

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

in the manifest file. Actually, on google play all those devices above SDK version 7 shall see my app. Yet google developer console shows me that some number of devices are supported. But my app is installable and usable in such devices in which play store doesn't show this app.
Shall I add other statements like

```
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.location"
android:required="false" />
```

I would like to use a ready made full list of such feature request, so that my app is visible to almost all devices.

Comment: Please post your entire manifest, as you have it in the app in the Play Store.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but I've just checked and Android Studio tells me this:
**"By targeting API level 7 and later, your app will run on approximately 100.0% of the devices that are active on Google Play Store."**